# Git deploy in autoscaling environment (Google Cloud Instance Group)

Tags: git, bitbucket, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking to use something like git hooks or webhooks to cleanly deploy new code (pushed to a BitBucket Repo) to multiple machines in an autoscaling environment (specifically a Google Cloud Instance Group).

Currently I'm using cron to run the following task every minute on my virtual machines:

`cd /var/www/mywebsite.com && git pull -q origin master && sudo composer update`

Clearly this is not an efficient method.

What is the most efficient way to deploy code to multiple machines?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you could solve this problem. Here are two possibilities:

### Using a message broker

One possibility would me to have all your instances subscribe to some sort of message broker (etcd? rabbitmq? zmq pub socket? redis?), and have a web service that will receive the notification from github, then broadcast a message on your local message bus that will be received by all of your running instances, which can then run the necessary `git pull` locally.

### Using ssh

Another solution would be to have a web service that receives a notification from github and then uses `ssh` to log into all your instances and run the `git` command. You could use a tool like Ansible to help automate this process.

---

Both of these solutions obviously require a stable address at which you run the web service that receives notifications from github.  This could be a dedicated machine, or it could be a floating ip address that could be serviced by any one of your instances.  These are all implementation details.

### Other possibilities

GitHub can directly integrate with a number of third-party services.  Possibly some of those services are designed to help solve exactly this problem; I haven't looked at them in any detail but that's probably worth a little research.

Comment: Thanks, the SSH method would be the most straight forward. I guess the way to do that is to have i.e. a PHP file on a separate instance that gets called by a webhook from Bitbucket, that lists all active instances in a group, SSH into each, and perform a git pull in the git directory.